# Dynamic tool to test Java code for deadlocks and race conditions

Tags: gratis, java, software-testing

I am searching for a tool to allow me to test a Java application and find deadlocks and races in it.

### Research

I understand there are two main approaches, static or dynamic. That is, static code analysis, or instrumented execution.

I am interested in instrumented execution, because static analysis has unacceptable false positive rate for my purpose, whereas instrumented execution has essentially zero false positives. I am already using static analyzer (Coverity Scan for Open Source) and I just don't have the time (and expertise) to go through potential issues it reports and triage them.

There too seem to be two approaches to instrumented execution. Either I the programmer am given power to influence thread scheduling, with something like [Thread Weaver](https://github.com/google/thread-weaver), or the tool is automatically trying various promising thread schedules, like [CalFuzzer](https://github.com/ksen007/calfuzzer).

CalFuzzer seems pretty much dead, it took me half a day to just make it run the example tests attached to the project on Java 8 and I worry what obstacles will come next...

### Question

Do you know of any such automated tools like CalFuzzer that are free to use, work for Java programs, and have a healthy and active community around them?